# Couchdb's Update Event Handler in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchdb

I want to create an app in Node.js.
This app modified a document, lets say :

```
{_id: xxx, text: "Hello"}
```

every time this document is changed, i want to execute a function in my node.js app.
So it's something roughly like this

```
$db.on('update', function(id){
   console.log("There are changes in " + id)
})
```

How can I do this with Node.js ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for couchdb's [changes](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/database/changes.html) feed. Every time a document is updated in the `db`, to which you have subscribed to, a notification is sent. You can simply listen on that notification and execute your code.

You can also subscribe to particular document id's. See the [request options](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/database/changes.html) in the POST request.

Also since you are using node js I suggest you take a look at the [follow library](https://github.com/iriscouch/follow). It makes what you want to do a lot easier.

Example:-

```
    var follow = require('follow');

     follow({db: "<database name here>", include_docs:true}, 
       function(error, change) {
       if(!error) {
           console.log(change.doc) // updated doc
           console.log("Got change number " + change.seq + ": " + change.id);
       }
     });
```

Comment: Easy enough to follow.. so it'll be a sin if i don't add some example here. Thank you @Akhsat!

Comment: @dennylooks I included your edit. Looks like it was rejected before. Thanks for the example :)